# Web viewer in react not working , what to do

Tags: reactjs

Compiled with problems:X

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-webview/lib/WebView.js
```

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/pathparakh/Projects/react/new/new/node_modules/react-native-webview/lib/WebView.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (5:37):

```
  3 | // This "dummy" WebView is to render something for unsupported platforms,
  4 | // like for example Expo SDK "web" platform.
> 5 | var WebView = function () { return (<View style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
    |                                     ^
  6 |       <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>
  7 |           React Native WebView does not support this platform.
  8 |       </Text>
```

this is error
[image]

and when i created app it is showing
[image]

i also run npm audit fix --force

this is showing error when i add

```
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
```

in app.js

this is package.json

```
{
  "name": "new",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add @babel/preset-react to your babel config presets or @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx to babel config plugins as error suggests? Please also provide package.json.

Comment: added, in last 3rd line there is babel

Comment: If you don't have babel.config.js or .babelrc in your project root try to add it and add @babel/preset-react to presets like in docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets

Comment: i run command "npm i babel-preset-react-native --save-dev " but no file added